# How to implement a generic trait method in Scala 3 when the generic and concrete signatures match?

Tags: scala, generics, overriding, scala-3

Following code compiles fine in Scala 2.13.12, but not in Scala 3.3.1:

```scala
trait Vectoric[V] {
  def times(a: V, f: Double): V
  def times(a: V, b: V): V
}

object DoubleIsVectoric extends Vectoric[Double] {
  def times(a: Double, f: Double) = a * f
}
```

The error is:

> Failure to disambiguate overloaded reference with
>
> method times in trait Vectoric: (a: V, b: V): V  and
>
> method times in trait Vectoric: (a: V, f: Double): V [7:7]

To me the semantics seem to be obvious and the method should implement both parent methods, but no matter what I try, I cannot make Scala 3 compiler to accept my code.

How can I implement trait like this when the method signatures match for the particular value of the type parameter?

Answer (score 1):

In Scala 3, the issue arises due to the stricter rules for method overloading.

Back to the Scala 2 compiled version, the `Vectoric` trait promises two different `times` methods. *Au contraire*, the `DoubleIsVectoric` object does expose just one times `method`. This is kind of a lie.

I would suggest to you two possible solutions.

The former is the more obvious: avoid method overloading altogether and use different method names.

```scala
trait Vectoric[V] {
  def times(a: V, f: Double): V
  def multiply(a: V, b: V): V
}

given DoubleIsVectoric: Vectoric[Double] with {
  def times(a: Double, f: Double) = a * f
  def multiply(a: Double, b: Double) = a * b
}
```

The latter will preserve the *twins* taking advantage of the **Value Object** concept from DDD.

```scala
case class Scalar(value: Double)

trait Vectoric[V] {
  def times(a: V, f: Scalar): V
  def times(a: V, b: V): V
}

object DoubleIsVectoric extends Vectoric[Double] {
  def times(a: Double, f: Scalar) = a * f.value
  def times(a: Double, f: Double) = a * f
}
```

Meanwhile, a bonus solution came to my mind. The `Scalar` class is meant to be a simple value type, so it should extends the `AnyVal` class. You could not extend that way because `Double` and `Scalar` will have the same type after erasure. The Scala **call-by-name** capability will rescue us:

```scala
case class Scalar(value: Double) extends AnyVal

trait Vectoric[V] {
  def times(a: V, f: => Scalar): V
  def times(a: V, b: V): V
}

object DoubleIsVectoric extends Vectoric[Double] {
  def times(a: Double, f: => Scalar) = a * f.value
  def times(a: Double, f: Double) = a * f
}
```